# Density plot in R sometimes gives frequency, other times probabilities?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Plotting the density of some of my data yields frequencies on the Y axis, while plotting the density of other data yields probabilities(?) on the Y axis. Is there an equivalent of freq=FALSE for density() like there is for hist() so I can have control over this? I've tried searching around for this specific issue, but I almost always end up getting hist() documentation instead of finding the answer to this specific question. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some example data as well as your plotting commands.

Comment: When you make a proper density plot, you're plotting neither frequency nor probability values on the y-axis; you are plotting an estimate of the probability density function for your observed data. Perhaps you might want to review how [density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation) works or what exactly a [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is.

Comment: plot(density(tmt_peptides_txt_allcols$PEP),lwd=2,xlab="PEP Score",main="Posterior Error Probability",xlim=c(-0.0005,0.0015),ylim=c(0,1750),bty="n") yields this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LmiqDiw_t0TjJOWVRXQl9wMlU&authuser=0 . Since the values on the Y axis are > 1 I thought they might be frequencies or something. Could you please explain why they aren't < 1?

Answer (score 2):

Adding such a parameter to density would be statistically unwise for the reasons articulated by @MrFlick. If you want to convert a density estimate to be on the same scale as the observations, you can multiply by the length of the vector used for the density calculation. The density then becomes a "per x unit" estimate of "frequency". Compare the two plots:

```
set.seed(123);x <- sample(1:10, size=5 )
#> x
#[1] 3 8 4 7 6
 plot(density(x))

 plot(5*density(x)$y)
```

The "per unit of x" estimate is now in the correct (approximate) range of 0.5 (and it's integral should be roughly equal to the counts). It's only accidentally that an x value of a density would ever be similar to a probability. It should always be that the integral of the density is unity.

Perhaps you are looking for the `ecdf` function? Instead of returning a density , it provides a mechanism for constructing a cumulative probability function.